# Text on image mouseover?

Tags: css, image, text, mouseover

I am trying to get a small box to appear on the bottom-left side of an image when a mouse moves over it. Inside the box there will be a link to a different page.

[Here](http://theme-frsch2.tumblr.com/) is somewhat similar to what I want, but the box to be smaller and not connected to the border of the image.

I've tried everything and can't find an answer. And I don't want to use tooltip, let alone the fact that i have no javascript knowledge whatsoever. I really want this to be CSS.

Also the images I'm trying to work with can be found [right here.](http://silentthemes.tumblr.com)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is using the `:hover` pseudoelement in CSS3.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="hover" />
    <p class="text">text</p>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:30px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

​Demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Pghz/3/).

---

This instead is a way of achieving the same result by using jquery:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="hover" />
    <p class="text">text</p>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper p {
position:relative;
bottom:30px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

**jquery code:**

```
$('.hover').mouseover(function() {
  $('.text').css("visibility","visible");
});

$('.hover').mouseout(function() {
  $('.text').css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

You can put the jquery code where you want, in the **body** of the HTML page, then you need to include the jquery library in the **head** like this:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You can see the demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/RetMp/1/).

When you want to use it on your website, just change the `<img src />` value and you can add multiple images and captions, just copy the format i used: insert image with `class="hover"` and p with `class="text"`

Comment: Thank you Fabio, this works as well, but the other is simple. I will look into this when I start playing with javascript more :)

Comment: you are welcome :) javascript is similar to java as you can guess from the name, but simpler. If you want to learn it i recommend you the course that you can find at codecademy.com . It's not a boring one, you have to code while learning. Besides jquery is a javascript framework that lets you code powerful things in a easier way than using pure javascript. The official documentation is well done :) @alexr

Answer (score 19):

Here is one way to do this using css

**HTML**

```
<div class="imageWrapper">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" alt="" />
    <a href="http://google.com" class="cornerLink">Link</a>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```css
.imageWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.imageWrapper img {
    display: block;
}
.imageWrapper .cornerLink {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;

}
.imageWrapper:hover .cornerLink {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UqdVp/1/)**

Or if you just want it in the bottom left corner:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UqdVp/2/)**

Comment: You can use `display: block` and `display: none` rather than opacity if you like. I prefer to have the nice transition though.

Comment: yes it's right. It has a nicer effect. I didn't know you can change the properties of another element on hover. I thought only the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to play with a bit before I got it working correctly, but this was exactly what I needed!!! Thanks 3dgoo!

Answer (score 6):

And if you come from even further in the future you can use the title property on div tags now to provide tooltips:

```
<div title="Tooltip text">Hover over me</div>
```

Let's just hope you're not using a browser from the past.

```html
<div title="Tooltip text">Hover over me</div>
```

Comment: great and elegant solution. Is it normal for there to be a second of delay latency from the time the hover text should appear? There is a bit of a delay

Comment: Unfortunately this method relies on the browser to show the tooltip and comes with a delay

Answer (score 0):

For people coming from the future, you can now do this purely in CSS.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; 
  margin: 5rem;
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;

  width: 120px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```