# WordPress mouse over text with background color?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I m new to wordpress and using 4.2.2 version. I need to show mouse over background color with text on image. The given text and images are generating dynamically from the admin panel. I have given the below images for your reference, first image right now im having my site, and next image I need to do like that.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text on image mouseover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149360/text-on-image-mouseover)

Comment: There is already a fiddle existing here. http://jsfiddle.net/4LjeL/2/

Comment: Thanks sagar, i'll check this and how to integrate in WordPress.

Comment: I am using enfold theme, in this i dont know which file is working for show the outputs. This is my site and my page, (http://ef.efvoice.com/ef/?page_id=132) i need to know the file path for this. Can pls tell me. I struggling in this for couple of days.

Comment: Finally i write in css and show the mouse over with text. Thank you for all your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for wordpress

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $unfiltered ); ?>
```

Here is the codex

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata

With this u can get the name of the image and show like the Sagar said

You'll use this in your page, not in yout functions.php

U won't be this in the functions, you'll use this in your page, like this

```
<?php 
     $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=eventos&category_name=galeria_evento&posts_per_page=1');
                    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
                        ?>

                    <?php
                        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                        $args = array(
                                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                                        'numberposts' => -1,
                                        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                                        'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id()
                                    );

                   // making the list of the attachments
                        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                        if ( $attachments ) {
                            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                            // getting the image and title of the attachment
                            echo "<div class='item-slide'><p class='title-slide'>".apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title )."</p>".wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' )."</div>";                                
                            }
                        }
                    ?>


            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: The photos coming from the wordpress page, so how can i include the functions. i think i need to edit the page or template file to put these functions right? Then i need to find which css file working for these page nd include the css codes right? i m confusing to write codes in which file.

Comment: No, u don't need to change so much the code, just use the foreach for take the attachments, and use the wp_get_attachment_meta($id) for take the atributtes about the attachment in the foreach, i'll find where i use this one time and put the code here

Comment: in side themes, in which file i need to add this function

Comment: I have find the file place, here already this function there. This is the function, inside the post.php file.                                                   function wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_id = 0, $unfiltered = false ) {
 $post_id = (int) $post_id;
 if ( !$post = get_post( $post_id ) )
  return false;

 $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );

 if ( $unfiltered )
  return $data;

 
 return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_metadata', $data, $post->ID );
}

Comment: In this function what i need to add. Can u pls tell me

Comment: I edited the answer, u will use this in your page not in your functions

Comment: The above code i need to write inside theme ,page.php or where i need to add. I have checked this code in page.php but it not working.

Comment: I am using enfold theme, in this i dont know which file is working for show the outputs. This is my site and my page, (http://ef.efvoice.com/ef/?page_id=132) i need to know the file path for this. Can pls tell me. I struggling in this for couple of days.

Comment: U are getting the title, now u just put a title in your image inside wordpress in the tab "Media"

Comment: yes john there i already added. Now i customized in css and show the text what i need. Thanks for your  support.

Comment: Your welcome, u use these function or other way to show?