# ID or Class on an Image Tag does not work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position some images for a site, and I've given the images different IDs so i may position them differently. On my css when i started the positioning it wouldn't work. either by ID or Class,

I placed these images inside a div just to check if everything is well, and I guess to easily point the exact img tags I want to use.

the code follows:

<--html-->

```
<div class="resume">
    <a  href="#"><img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:100px; max-height:100px;"src="imgs/pdf.png" class="pdf" ></a>
    <a  href="#"><img id="word" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:100px; max-height:100px;"src="imgs/mword.png" ></a>
    <img id="pline" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:100px; max-height:100px;"src="imgs/line1.png" >
    <img id="wline" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:100px; max-height:100px;"src="imgs/line2.png" >
</div>
```

<--css-->

```
.resume img 
{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
}

.resume img .pdf 
{
    position: relative;
    top:500px;
}
```

So if anyone could help me where I went wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no space between `img` and `.pdf`. This means an img tag containing an element (or elements) with class `.pdf`. `img.pdf` means img tags with this class.

For an id you would just use `#pline`, there would be no need to use `img#pline` because id's are unique on the page, and `img #pline` would be incorrect as described above.

Comment: ohh, well thank you so much kind Sir! This knowledge has mad me realized a lot. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Hello again kind sir, and thank you again, now I have added a hover event in css that would show some text, but would not work, I also use this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149360/text-on-image-mouseover as reference. Here is a link to the code

http://jsfiddle.net/Rinkemiku/qthcucmh/3/

Comment: `img.pdf:hover #pname` The img does not, and cannot, contain a p-tag, which is what you are targeting. If you need help with this then you should write it up as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

There should be no space between the element and the class in your case. i.e it must be `img.pdf`.***These are level 3 selectors which look for the specific namespace.***

---

**For EG:** 
The following assigns style only to H1 elements with `class~="pastoral"`:

```
H1.pastoral { color: green }  /* H1 elements with class~=pastoral */
```

Given these rules, the first H1 instance below would not have green text, while the second would:

```
<H1>Not green</H1>
<H1 class="pastoral">Very green</H1>
```

Comment: Thank you! these explains a lot

Comment: @rinkemiku: Welcome. you can +1 if it helped :)

Comment: Hello again kind sir, and thank you again, now I have added a hover event in css that would show some text, but would not work, I also use this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/14149360/text-on-image-mouseover as reference. Here is a link to the code  If you could help, I would enormously appreciate it

http://jsfiddle.net/Rinkemiku/qthcucmh/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
.resume img.pdf {
  position: relative;
  top:500px;
}
```

Comment: please explain how your code achieves the goal the OP is reaching for. this may seem obvious to you and other experienced programmers. If you provide clear explanation of your code it will lead to better answers on SO and also more upvotes

Comment: for the img.pdf it will search for image with pdf class and for img .pdf it will search for .pdf in img tag.