# How to add text when hovering

Tags: html, css, image

https://codepen.io/dhanushbadge/pen/uJkcq

Hi, my question is about adding adding icons and text when hovering at the img.
When hovering it shows gray but I want it to also show with 3 icons and a text on top. I can't seem to add text inside the circle when hovering.
The original code is in the link
Please helppppppppp

```css
html {
  font-size:62.5%;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  font-size:1.4rem;
  font-family:arial;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
img {
  border:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#team {
  max-width:96rem;
  width:100%;
  min-height:200px;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:white;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  align-items:center;
  -webkit-justify-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
  -webkit-flex-direction:row;
  flex-direction:row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  -webkit-align-content:flex-end;
  align-content:flex-end;
}
figure {
  width:12.5rem;
  height:12.5rem;
  display:block;
  margin:0.5rem 1rem 4rem 0.5rem;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:content-box;
  color:black;
}
figure img {
  -webkit-border-radius:50%;
  -moz-border-radius:50%;  
  border-radius:50%; 
}
#team figure img {
  -webkit-transition:opacity 0.26s ease-out;   
  -moz-transition:opacity 0.26s ease-out;   
  -ms-transition:opacity 0.26s ease-out;   
  -o-transition:opacity 0.26s ease-out;   
  transition:opacity 0.26s ease-out;
 
   
}
#team:hover img, #team:active img {
  opacity:1;
}
#team:hover img:hover, #team:active img:active   {
  opacity:0.3;
 
}
figcaption {
  font-size:1.2rem;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="team">
  <figure><img src="http://500px.com/graphics/pages/team/squares/oleg.jpg"><figcaption>Oleg Gutsol</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img             src="http://500px.com/graphics/pages/team/squares/evgeny.jpg"><figcaption>Evgeny Tchebotarev</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="http://500px.com/graphics/pages/team/squares/dustin.jpg"><figcaption>Dustin Plett</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="http://500px.com/graphics/pages/team/squares/adam.jpg"><figcaption>Adam Shutsa</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="http://500px.com/graphics/pages/team/squares/roxy.jpg"><figcaption>Roxy Keshavarznia</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="http://500px.com/graphics/pages/team/squares/eric.jpg"><figcaption>Eric Akaoka</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="http://500px.com/graphics/pages/team/squares/david.jpg"><figcaption>David Charlec</figcaption></figure>
  
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to solve a javascript problem with CSS, which has limited capacity to add elements. This should get you started in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149360/text-on-image-mouseover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

## 1. Pure HTML and CSS (no Javascript or JQuery)

See [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chiperific/9z8jgzLm/)

First, add your text and icons into the HTML. It looks like you can add them inside the `<figure>` block.

Second, add a CSS rule that only shows these elements when the figure is `:hover`-ed [Learn more about the :hover pseudo-class here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Third, tweak the `position`, or `margins` of the elements to get them to display where you want.

## 2. HTML and CSS and JQuery

See [This Other Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chiperific/wvtjrc7w/)

Still add your HTML elements with a unique class (I used "hoverable").

Still set your CSS to hide these elements by default. Either `visibility:hidden;` or `display:none;`

Then add some JQuery which watches for the `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` events to toggle the visibility or display of the elements.

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to do something like this (see hover with caption) https://codepen.io/kw7oe/pen/mPeepv

To achieve this you need to structure your html as so

```
<figure>
  <img src="" alt="">
  <span class="caption">{content}</span>
</figure>
```

The span class in this case has opacity 0 by default and changes to opacity 1 on hover. Using some css transition, we get a smooth appear and disappear effect. Figure in this case would have a relative positioning so that the span could be absolute hover over the entire thing.

```
figure { position: relative; display: block; overflow: hidden; }
figure img { max-width: 100% }
figure .caption { position: absolute; display: block; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; opacity: 0; transition: all .2s ease-in-out }
figure:hover .caption { opacity: 1; }
```

You can easily search for **image hover caption** on codepen and find a quite a few nice examples.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with jquery like below example:

```
$("#team img").each(function(){

  $(this).hover(
    function() {
      $(this).text("worked");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).text("");
    }

 );
});
```

Comment: how about only in css and html :(

Comment: but this is also right and mark tick if this is right please.

Comment: Plus, this is hard to style and she mentioned wanting to position the text and icons on top.

Comment: we can do this easily :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript or some css trick for that. 
css trick 
- you can provide some divs containing your desire design. and put it as hidden then show it when the img hovered.
javacript
- same as css but the code written in js haha :).

Answer (score 0):

As @John Joseph mentioned, this can be achieved easily using CSS. Here's a PURE CSS approach.

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-container">
<div class="image-cover" style="display:none;">
      <img src="your_icon"/>
      <span> your_text </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-container{
    background-image: url(your_image);
    position: relative;
}

.image-container:hover .image-cover{
    display:block;
}

.image-cover{
  position:absolute;
}
```